# How do I install the Cisco VPN client?

Tags: vpn, cisco

What is best way to install a Cisco VPN client application in Ubuntu?

Comment: Which client are we talking about here?  VPNC?  AnyConnect?  Or the network-manager-vpnc plug-in?  Or are you asking "what clients are available?"  in which case, I might just have answered you in this comment...

Comment: am not sure ..the configuration that i have , `name, password ,Authentication Type: Group Authentication,Transport Type: IPSec over UDP,Public IP address` , normally i install Cisco vpn client application and add the configuration in windows BUT now am using ubuntu which application should i use ??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to install network-manager-vpnc, then configure it through network manager.

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
```

That will install `vpnc`, `network-manager-vpnc` and `network-manager-vpnc-gnome`.

Now LEFT click on your network manager applet :

[image: Network Manager]

And choose "Configure VPN...", then click "Add" and drop the menu to "Cisco Compatible VPN".

[image: VPN Configureation]

And enter your details.  To start your VPN, just follow the steps again, but instead of "Configure VPN", you'll click on the entry you created.

Comment: i experienced strange "restart your pc to make authentication work" problem with this. If it says "wrong authentification just try to restart your pc".

Comment: vpn connection failed...i tried make restart many times....same issue....

Comment: should i install cisco certificate...encryption method should be the same .....

Comment: You can also do a "sudo killall NetworkManager" instead of a full reboot.

Comment: also if your administrator gives you a .pcf file (or you can find it on a windows machine), you can just hit import and all your connection details will get filled in automagically.

Comment: After I installing network-manager-vpnc, my connection type still only supports PPTP VPN. I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @JayWong I had to manually `sudo apt install network-manager-vpnc-gnome` for it to show up in the GUI.

Comment: If you don't have a **group password**, after you click on **Add VPN**, you should choose **Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN(openconnect)** instead of **Cisco Compatible VPN (vpnc)**.

Comment: Currently using Ubuntu 20 and I also had to manually do what @FriendFX said `sudo apt install network-manager-vpnc-gnome`

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be a problem on 16.04 with Cisco VPN when installing only network-manager-vpnc. Option for Cisco VPN simply doesn't show in the list.

Another solution is to install

```
sudo apt-get install openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

then restart network manager. Unfortunately I am unable to provide auth details.

Last but not least is to do this by manually adding file to /etc/vpnc and running it through vpnc command, this one should work, more about it here: https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-connect-to-a-cisco-vpn-with-vpnc/

edit: I probably missed installing something, this works for GUI version:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

Answer (score 2):

Btw, as a performance tip after successfully installing following `Scaine`'s answer, you might also want to [enable the option to only use the VPN connection for resources on its network](http://www.unfoldingcode.com/2011/08/how-to-install-cisco-vpn-client-on.html).

Comment: good advice, another is to check that the NAT transversal is correct, for my place of work I need to use "cisco-UDP". another one is set up local routes (e.g. 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0) to use the local gateway (e.g. 192.168.1.254) (this is important to print in local network printers).

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way to use Cisco VPN installing kvpnc which is a vpn client for different vpn; I used it and it is quite simple to use. It is available directly in the Ubuntu Software Center:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/kvpnc/